# xxx cannot be deleted because it is not empty. TFS release:perform

Tags: maven, tfs, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to make a release with tfs. I am stuck at mvn `release:perform` now. I finished mvn `release:prepare` successfully and then tried mvn `release:perform` and got this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building releaseTestName 1.13-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) @ releaseTestName ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] scmUrl - xxx
[INFO] workspace: myWorkSpace
[INFO] checkinPolicies: True
[INFO] Scheme - https
[INFO] Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf workspace -login:xxx -new "-comment:Creating workspace for maven command" -server:xxx"
[INFO] err - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

[INFO] Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf workfold -login:xxx -unmap xxx"
[INFO] err - xxx does not match any mapping.

[INFO] Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf workfold -login:xxx -map xxx C:\..\..\target\checkout"
[INFO] err -
[INFO] Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf get -login:xxx -recursive -force -version:LreleaseTestName-1.12 C:\..\..\target\checkout"
[INFO] err - xxx cannot be deleted because it is not empty.
xxx cannot be deleted because it is not empty.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project releaseTestName: Unable to checkout from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] Error code for TFS checkout (get) command - 0
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] xxx cannot be deleted because it is not empty.
[ERROR] xxx cannot be deleted because it is not empty.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I also tried to specify a working directory somewhere outside this folder and received the same error. I Googled about this problem, and someone said that I should close all tabs that have this folder open, but I get the same error. Does someone know what the problem is? I'm guessing my scm is good because mvn `release:prepare` worked great.

Comment: "C:\..\..\target\checkout"try to delete target folder from git manually (from repository), you should ignore it by git anyway. Maven prepare uses this folder for running build inside build. Since it already exists, it cannot be cleared.

Comment: You have other errors before i.e. Command line - cmd.exe /X /C "tf workspace -login:xxx -new "-comment:Creating workspace for maven command" -server:xxx"
[INFO] err - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Fix those before

Comment: C:\E-Venue-tfs\Java\releaseTest\releaseTestName cannot be deleted because it is not empty. I think that maven is not complaining about target dir. Also, this time I deleted target dir before starting mvn release:perform(It was empty anyway). He is complaining about dir where my pom resides. Thank you for advice, but unfortunately my problem is still here.

Comment: try run -X and see what exactly are the errors and inputs; also try to remove target IN REPOSITORY. not on your machine

Comment: and final bit: check that your repository is open for push by anonymous

Comment: aw, wait. try to run release:clean release:prepare release:perform in one maven job

Comment: I guess @GiulioVian has right but I still don't know why my connection was closed. I tried to run in one release:clean release:prepare but I got same error. I don't have target dirs on tfs, but I have them in local repo. I guess that is because somehow maven cant push it to tfs, because connection is closed.

Comment: @Spasoje I would check the basics: the machine can connect, the account running the agent can connect, has the grant for read, for write operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I created new workspace in Microsoft visual studio and map my project somewhere outside all mapped folders. I had C:\Java mapped on some directory on TFS and then I create new dummy project inside C:\Java and tried to release that project and for some reason I couldn't do that. Then I mapped that dummy project somewhere on C:\test and this problem disappear. :)

Answer (score 0):

mvn release:prepare will build, remove the SNAPSHOT from the version, tag in SCM & update the version for the next SNAPSHOT iteration

mvn release:perform will checkout the tag from SCM, build and push to the repository (Nexus or similar)

You release:prepare is failing at the point when it tries to do the SCM tag.  You have set you password or login to TFS as xxxx.

It looks to me that you've set this up in Jenkins with an xxxx.